# What do you feel stands out strongly in a CV without industry experience?

Tags: experience

I've recently graduated from University and i'm making those first few steps into the industry and as yet, i have no industry experience. I'm in the process of writing my CV and putting it alongside my showreel but i feel i need something extra to really push myself ahead of everyone else. i feel my sonic styling is very different to most people but i'm apprehensive that my lack of industry experience will let me down.

From personal experience, what is something that stood out about you or that you noticed in someone else that really made the difference?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I've looked at thousands of CVs over the years, sometimes several hundred for one job. The best of them always identified relevant strengths, and how those strengths were demonstrated/acquired. The vast majority of the CVs I had to wade through, gave only a chronological list of degrees/diplomas/work experience and made me work to find a reason to interview. 
Read a few books about writing CVs. You may get an insight and ideas for constructing a non-chronological CV.
My advise is to tailor each CV for a specific job. Identify specifics they are looking for. Show you have relevant qualities - and a bit more. Show you have researched the Co. and why you want to work for them.
Don't forget generic qualities - the ability to get-on with others, leadership potential, track record of hard work & success. You may have excelled at sport/anything in school, was it a team, have you been team captain ? Think outside the box, your life experiences may demonstrate abilities and potential that are a lot more appealing than work experience. 
Last, make the CV easy to read, and capture attention early on. Print it on a good quality clean paper. Make absolutely certain there are no spelling or grammatical errors, or, no lies/errors about qualifications, grades, or any other claim you make. 
Good luck with the interviews !